# Accept changes on datagridview as selected item in Listbox change

Tags: c#, datagridview, listbox

I'm struggling with with accepting changes to my datagridview.

I have a listbox and a datagridview. My datagridview changes based on the selected index which is selecte from the listbox. However, each time I select a different item, the datagridview items goes back to the original view/list.

My question: How can I accept/write changes back to my datatable or prevent the datagridview from refreshing everytime I select an item from the listbox?

The code for my listbox change event is:

```
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow[] result = ds.Tables["AssessmentItems"].Select("GroupId = " + listBox1.SelectedIndex);

        var newTable = result.CopyToDataTable();
        BindingSource bindSource = new BindingSource();
        bindSource.DataSource = newTable;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindSource;
    }
```

Comment: I guess you want to filter your source without refreshing it. right?

Comment: 100% correct. And then export/save the datagridview because the last column is a combobox with options PASS & FAIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you want to export your source, dont refresh it, filter it. `BindingSource` has a `.Filter` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx)  which will help you. change your event to this. done!

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bindSource = new BindingSource();
    bindSource.DataSource = yourOrginalSource;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindSource;
    //set your bind source filter
    string myFilter = "GroupId = " + listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    source.Filter = myFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.databind();
```

needs to called for update in gridview for new changes i think.

Answer (score 0):

Just set **Filter** property of `bindingsource`. But you need to declare bindingsource as you can use from any method in your class.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindSource.Filter = "GroupId = " + listBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```